# Array is in a Descending or Ascending order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a job interview and they gave me a few questions to practice on
one of them is:
Check if Array is in a Descending or Ascending order and alert message if Descending and if Ascending, and none of the above if not sorted.

this is what I wrote but it's not working :

```
for ( i = 0; i < myArrey2.length; i++) {
    if (myArrey2[i] > myArrey2[i + 1]) {
        alert ("Ascending");
    } else if(myArrey2[i] < myArrey2[i + 1]){
        alert ("Descending");
    }else {
        alert("not sorrted");
    }
    break;
}
```

can somebody assist me whit this one?
thanks for the help.

Comment: How isn't it working? Is it outputting an error? Are you not getting the correct results?

Comment: You're just checking adjacent elements, not the whole array.

Comment: You must not alert something in every iteration.

Comment: A simple way is to make a copy of the array and sort it. Then see if the original array and the sorted array are the same.

Comment: I get wrong result, for example if the array is [7,5,8,9] I get a message that Says the array is in ascending order  and I need to be allerted that the array is not sorrted

Answer (score 0):

Check the order of the first two elements of the array. Then go through the rest of the array, checking if they're in the same order.

```
var order;
if (a[0] > a[1]) { // first two are descending
    order = "Descending";
    for (var i = 1; i < a.length-1; i++) {
        if (a[i] <= a[i+1]) {
            order = "Not ordered";
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    order = "Ascending";
    for (var i = 1; i < a.length-1; i++) {
        if (a[i] > a[i+1]) {
            order = "Not ordered";
            break;
        }
    }
}
console.log(order);
```

This assumes that all the numbers are different. If they can be equal, you need to skip past any series of equal elements at the beginning of the array, until you find the first unequal pair.

The important thing to remember when trying to determine something about a whole array is that you can't know that it's true until you get to the end of the loop. So you can't report that it's ascending or descending each time through the the loop -- all you know is that those two elements are ascending or descending, you still haven't determined anything about the rest of the array. On the other hand, as soon as the condition is false, you can break out of the loop, there's no need to check the rest of the array.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me a lot, it finally works! @Barmar thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, loop through the array from the second element to the end in order to create an array of the changes from one item to the next by subtracting the previous one from it. Then, check to see if all of the items are exactly the same (all changes equal 0). Should that not be the case, check to see if the array is sorted in ascending order (all changes are greater than or equal to 0). If not, check to see if the array is sorted in descending order (all changes are less than or equal to 0). Finally, if the array does not fall into any of these three categories, it is unordered.

```
function order(arr) {
  const deltas = [];

  for(let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    deltas.push(arr[i] - arr[i - 1]);
  }

  if(deltas.every(change => change === 0)) {
    return 'Both ascending and descending as every element is exactly the same.';
  } else if(deltas.every(change => change >= 0)) {
    return 'Ascending';
  } else if(deltas.every(change => change <= 0)) {
    return 'Descending';
  }

  return 'None';
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this,it is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows;

The returned values should be interpreted as follows;

```
[ true,  true  ]   // ascending orderly
[ false, true  ]   // descending orderly
[ _,     false ]   // not sorted
```

```js
function check([x1, x2,...xs], s = [true, true]){
  return xs.length ? [x1 < x2, s[1] && check([x2,...xs], [x1 < x2, (x1 < x2 && s[0]) === x1 < x2])[1]] 
                   : [x1 < x2, s[0] === x1 < x2];
}

var as = [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    bs = [6,5,4,3,2,1],
    cs = [6,5,3,4,2,1];
    
console.log(check(as));
console.log(check(bs));
console.log(check(cs));
```